Change woocommerce Email header image
i have 4 woocommerce pruducts and i want one email header image for one product and another email header image for the other 3 products. I am trying to change the email-header.php but the code doesnt work. Can you help me ? this is the code that i am trying:
                                    <?php
                                    // Captura o pedido global (se disponível)
                                    global $current_order;
                                    $product_ids = [];

                                    // Verifica se existe um pedido associado
                                    if ( isset( $current_order ) && $current_order instanceof WC_Order ) {
                                        foreach ( $current_order->get_items() as $item ) {
                                            $product_ids[] = $item->get_product_id();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // Define a imagem de cabeçalho com base nos IDs dos produtos
                                    if ( in_array( 3433, $product_ids ) ) {
                                        $img = 'https://ligadosvencedores.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/Barrra-e-mail.jpg';
                                    } elseif ( array_intersect( [ 5773, 5774, 5775 ], $product_ids ) ) {
                                        $img = 'https://ligadosvencedores.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/barra-emails.jpg';
                                    } else {
                                        // Imagem padrão configurada no WooCommerce
                                        $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' );
                                    }

                                    // Exibe a imagem do cabeçalho
                                    if ( $img ) {
                                        echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" /></p>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="template_container">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                                            <!-- Body -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="template_body">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top" id="body_content">
                                                        <!-- Content -->
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td valign="top">
                                                                    <div id="body_content_inner">

why this code is not working ?
